Exporting Armature/Bones from blender
I am trying to write a system for exporting rigged models from blender into a json format. There is one problem I have run into; I have my bones running vertically on the Z axis but my python code is exporting the matrices with the value decreasing on the Y axis, also the center 4 elements of my 4x4 matrices look like they have been rotated 90 degrees around the X axis. Is there something I need to do in blender for this to be oriented correctly?

my exporting code....
def matrix_to_list(matrix):
ret = []
for row in matrix:
    for element in row:
        ret.append(element)
return ret

        for bone in obj.parent.data.bones:
        boneinfo = {
            "id": boneid,
            "name": bone.name,
            "parent": "",
            "inverse_bind_pose": matrix_to_list(bone.matrix_local.inverted())
        }

the resulting json...
    "bones": [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Bone",
        "parent": "",
        "inverse_bind_pose": [
            1.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
            0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 1.0
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bone.001",
        "parent": "Bone",
        "inverse_bind_pose": [
            1.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -2.0,
            0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 1.0
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bone.002",
        "parent": "Bone.001",
        "inverse_bind_pose": [
            1.0, -0.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -4.0,
            0.0, -1.0, 0.0, -0.0,
            -0.0, 0.0, -0.0, 1.0
        ]
    }
]


Are you aware that the "local" position of bones is relative to their parent? And that for bones, Y is the bone axis?

no, but that does make sense. although what do you mean "Y is the bone axis"?

Bone points to local Y
